# Skype symbol in cover letter made with moderncv latex

Tags: symbols, skype

I want to include the skype symbol in the cover letter made with modern cv. 
I cannot find anything that suites me. I found several cases where the symbol of skype was included after the command \begin{document}. I want to include the skype symbol before.

Here below a working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\makeatletter
\definecolor{ashgrey}{rgb}{0.7, 0.75, 0.71}
\moderncvstyle{classic}    

\newcommand\subject[1]{\def\@subject{#1}}          % style options are 'casual' 
\moderncvcolor{green}                              % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', the 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace 

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\name{XXXX}{XXXX}
\address{XXXX
}{XXXX}
\phone[mobile]{XXXX}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{XXXX}                           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\justify
\sloppy


\recipient{\mdseries To XXXX}{Phone: XXXX\\ XXXX \\ XXXX \\ XXXX}

\date{\today}

\title{Some fancy title}
\opening{ \textbf{:XXXXX} 

\end{document}
```